# Changing cycles in Interval Running Application on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to write an application in Android Studio for Interval Running. I have a problem with one algorithm aplication. First i will write what the application should do.
Interval Running is running with diferent pace, slower and faster. My application will tell the runner what he should do right now - running fast, running slow, walking etc. - some kind of assistant. In application we input warmup (time we walk before running in seconds), relax (time we walk after running in the end in seconds), hispeed (how many seconds a cycle of high speed running lasts), lowspeed(how many seconds a cycle of low speed running lasts) and cycles (number of hispeed-lowspeed cycles). Everything is shown on this picture.

http://oi62.tinypic.com/66dphw.jpg

Application window (sorry for poor editing from my language in paint):

http://oi59.tinypic.com/2v2gza1.jpg

After START click all the calculations begin.
Overall time is correctly counted. Time left (from overall time to 0) is also OK. Everything works fine when the number of cycles is 1. If I want more lowspeed-hispeed cycles, the application works not correctly, and I can't figure out how to write this peace of code to make it work. Can someone halp me with this?

Source code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            am.setRingerMode(0);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            am.setRingerMode(1);
        }
    });
    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            am.setRingerMode(2);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void start(View view) {

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    warmup = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    relax = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());
    EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    hispeed = Integer.parseInt(editText3.getText().toString());
    EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    lowspeed = Integer.parseInt(editText4.getText().toString());
    EditText editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    cykle = Integer.parseInt(editText5.getText().toString());

    overall = warmup + relax + ((hispeed + lowspeed) * cykle);
    TextView textView13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
    textView13.setText("" + overall);


    final TextView textView12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(overall * 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

   //         int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000));

            textView12.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            int milis = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;

            if ((overall - milis) < warmup) {
                TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                textView8.setText("Warmup");
                                                 }
            if (((overall - milis) < warmup+hispeed) && ((overall - milis) > (warmup))){
                TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                textView8.setText("HiSpeed");
            }
            if (((overall - milis) < warmup+hispeed+lowspeed) && ((overall - milis) > (warmup+hispeed))){
                TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                textView8.setText("LowSpeed");
            }

            if ((overall - milis) > (overall - relax)) {
                TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                textView8.setText("Relax");
            }





        }
        public void onFinish() {

            textView12.setText("0");
            TextView textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            textView8.setText("Finish");
        }
    };

    Count.start();

    }

}
```